# Maven errors and build faliure

Tags: maven, build, dependencies

The following problem happened: once i opened Eclipe, all the procects were signed with a red X. Opening the projet tree, there was no error sign in the nodes. Nothig showed me what caused the errors. I could not build the projects. Finally i created a new workspace for Eclipse, checked out the projects from SVN, imported them as Maven projects. (There were two main and several child projects.)
Ther are still two projects showing the red X but not showing what causes the errors. I have tried to refresh, clean in Eclipse. I cannot build the other projects without error either, of course also not the ones with errors. The error message is e.g.:

```
    [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for hu.bz.ikti.insurance:SAMCommon:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT  
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ hu.bz.ikti.insurance:InSurance:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, C:\Dev\workspace\InSurance\pom.xml, line 27, column 12  
[WARNING]   
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.  
[WARNING]   
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.  
[WARNING]   
[INFO]                                                                           
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------  
[INFO] Building SAM-függő közös osztályok 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT  
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------  
[WARNING] The POM for hu.bz.ikti:common:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available  
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------  
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE  
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------  
[INFO] Total time: 1.110s  
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jul 12 11:33:33 CEST 2013  
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/114M  
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------  
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project SAMCommon: Could not resolve dependencies for project hu.bz.ikti.insurance:SAMCommon:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact hu.bz.ikti:common:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]  
[ERROR]   
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.  
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

And for the erroneus project part of the message is:

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project Service: Could not resolve dependencies for project hu.bz.ikti.insurance:Service:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE (compile), commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4 (compile), postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.1-901-1.jdbc4 (compile), org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE (compile), hu.bz.ikti.insurance:Model:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (compile), org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE (compile), hu.bz.ikti:service-base:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (compile), org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE (compile), org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.1 (compile)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for hu.bz.ikti.insurance:Model:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact hu.bz.ikti.insurance:Model:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT from/to ikti (https://fcd3.ikti.hu/artifactory/ext-release-local): Failed to transfer https://fcd3.ikti.hu/artifactory/ext-release-local/hu/bz/ikti/insurance/Model/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/Model-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom. Error code 409, The repository 'ext-release-local' rejected the artifact 'ext-release-local:hu/bz/ikti/insurance/Model/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/Model-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom' due to its snapshot/release handling policy. -> [Help 1]
```

Could anyone please help me?

**Edited:**

What does it mean:

> You are trying to deploy a snapshot version (Model-0.0.1-SNAPSHO‌​T.pom) into a releases-only repository ext-release-local ?
>   Select a snapshot repository (e.g. ext-snapshot-local) instead of a release one.

Should i change my pom.xml? How? I do not understand how is it possible that it earlier worked but now there is this compilation problem. What else could have been changed? I did not change anythig wih intention.

**Edited 2**

I also noticed that settings.xml under .m2 folder does not exist. Something really went wrong with Maven.

Comment: Important part of the message is "Error code 409, The repository 'ext-release-local' rejected the artifact 'ext-release-local:hu/bz/ikti/insurance/Model/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/Model-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom' due to its snapshot/release handling policy."  Check the remote repo (Nexus, Artifactory, or whatever) to find out what the issue is.

Answer (score 3):

As @user944849 mentioned, 409 is the important part.
You are trying to deploy a snapshot version (`Model-0.0.1-SNAPSHO‌​T.pom`) into a releases-only repository `ext-release-local`, thus the conflict.
Select a snapshot repository (e.g. `ext-snapshot-local`) instead of a release one.

Comment: Hi All,

My problem has resolved.
There was some problem with our repository. I deleted the reference to this. After that i was able to compile all projects.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled over this post with a slightly different problem: we tried to deploy an artifact `artifact-1.2.1.jar` to a Snapshot repository and got this error:

```
org.artifactory.api.repo.exception.RepoRejectException: Cannot deploy file
'artifact-1.2.1.jar'. The repository 'repo_snapshot' rejected the resolution
of an artifact 'repo_snapshot:xxx/artifact/1.2.1/artifact-1.2.1.jar' due to 
conflict in the snapshot release handling policy.
```

Problem for us was that `SNAPSHOT` was not part of the file name of the artifact, so renaming it to `artifact-1.2.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` solved the issue.